# How to Save a imagepicker with textview Data in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a `UITextView`, image picker and submit `UIButton` in a view. I want to save the data together, but since the `imagePickerController` uses a delegate method, it is called independently of when data is entered in the textview.

Should I temporarily save the image from the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method and then retrieve it when the submit button is clicked?

If so, how do I do this?

If not, how to I save the textview and image data at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I temporarily save the image from the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method and then retrieve it when the submit button is clicked?

Yes.

> If so, how do I do this?

```
@property (nonatomic) UIImage *lastSelectedImage;

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)thePicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    self.lastSelectedImage = image;
    [thePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]
}

- (void) buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    // do something with self.myTextView.text and self.lastSelectedImage
}
```